# Create a conditional column using a specific string as a delimiter in pentaho

Tags: sql, sql-server, pentaho

Im trying to create a conditional column in pentaho spliting by the delimiter "NF" on the image below...
I've tried a lot of things, like filter rows, split columns and etc, but as specif string being requested i think that is better way to do this, can someone help pls?

[image: new column by the delimiter "NF"]

I've tried filter rows, split fields, and a function in the formula step

Comment: If you have *"tried a lot of things"* then show those attempts in your question. *Explain* why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state the output you are trying to get from the column with the NF delimiter, lets say you are trying to get two new columns:

| IMPOSTOS | BEFORE_NF | AFTER_NF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PIS APURACAO S/NF 0001 TAG COMERCIO | PIS APURACAO S/ | 0001 TAG COMERCIO |
| COFINS APURACAO S/NF 0002 TAG COMERCIO | COFINS APURACAO S/ | 0002 TAG COMERCIO |

To get this outcome you can use the **Regex Evaluation** step, that uses this regex formula to separate your column:

```
(.*)(NF\s)(.*)
```

This separates your text in 3 groups: text before "NF ", the text "NF " and the text after "NF ".

The Regex evaluation step also has the ability to create another column with a flag to indicate if the regex formula was successful (the formula match the text or not).